# find out which program edited my hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts

I have this line in my hosts file:
x.x.x.x www.google.com

For many times, I saw this line missing from my hosts file while everything else in it stayed untouched. in this case I would add this line back to my hosts.

How can I monitor my hosts file to find out which program edited it secretly? 
PS. I am the only user of my conputer. nobody else ever touched it.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus program?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: I have avast anti-virus. And I'm using win7 x64 ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and leave it logging, but you'd have to leave it logging long enough to catch whatever is doing it in the act, then play around with the filter on the log to find what accessed **hosts**.

Comment: Set to filter on `WriteFile` operation and `Path` to the hosts file.